# Networking performance issue (Linux vs. BSD, or cabling?)

Tags: linux, networking

i.e. is it feasible? I have an old MacBook Pro and a Linux box with much faster hardware. Both are connected to the internet via a 1Gb switch to a 1Gb router to the modem. Plugging the early 2011 Mac directly into the modem yields a speedtest.net speed of 180Mb. With the router in between, it is about 90Mb and unchanged with switch + router. My high-powered Linux box (32GB RAM with 8-4GHz cores) gets up to almost 1/3 of these speeds. I am disappointed.

Comment: Linux is used in plenty of places where network speed is important so I seriously doubt that its network stack is not efficient. Personally I have copied files across a GigabitEthernet link at around 100Mbytes/sec. Most likely it's a matter of either application/protocol (a single FTP transfer can remain far below the available bandwidth) or of setup (the MTU size being often a culprit). Also, one of the lights on the Ethernet sockets on the machines tells you at what speed the link runs.

Comment: That is actually what I thought. The application is "speedtest.net" with a browser.Have you a hint about diagnosing the actual issue? That is a huge disparity. Both the Mac and the Linux have Gb ports and Cat 6 cables.  Maybe switching the switch ports, in case the issue is there? Who knows ....

Comment: Connect them back to back (you don't need crossed cables these days they will likely figure that out) and see what happens. When I did the copy above initially I had only 10MBytes/second, until I figured out that the switch (actually a 500Mbps CPL coupler) would only do 100MBps ethernet. Replaced it by a true Gigabit switch and that solved it. If I may be so bold, the current title of the question is an absolute turn-off for people who know, you would get a lot more help by asking a useful question such as "Network performance problems" and maybe add a small diagram.

Comment: I'm uncertain what "back to back" means. They are both currently connected to the same switch and the switch is one of two others (plus a VOIP device) plugged directly into the router. So I ran several speed tests, alternating between Linux and the Mac, yielding the observed results. (I do have cross-overs lying about, but my cables are all normally wired cat6.)

Comment: Back-to-back connected directly to each other with a crossover cable (although a straight cable should also work on modern machines)